# Issue creating borders with draw() / drawPolygon() in Graphics2D

Tags: java, polygon, shapes, paintcomponent, graphics2d

More adventures with `Graphics2D`!

This time I'm investigating the various paint / colour modes and ways to paint complex borders. The typical method is to fill the `Shape` or `Polygon`, and then draw the same `Shape` over the top (in a different colour). I'm familiar with setting `Strokes` and so forth to vary border thickness and other bits.

My latest attempt was to use `RadialGradientPaint` as a way of defining multiple bands of colour, but this doesn't appear to apply to the `draw` / `drawPolygon` call (or the extra colours aren't showing up.

The draw call is drawing a thickness 3 empty Polygon, but as a uniformly-blue strip. Below is the gradient / `paintComponent` code:

```
g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(h.getHexBorderWidth())); // this is set to 3
Point2D center = new Point2D.Float(50, 50);
float radius = 1;
float[] dist = {0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f};
Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE};

// the float value is defined as 0.0 in the constructor
RadialGradientPaint p =
    new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, new Point2D.Float(), dist, colors, 
         CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE);
g2d.setPaint(p);                    
if(((BasicHexagon) h).isAnimating()
    && ((BasicHexagon) h).getCurrentTransform() != null) { // just general null checks
    g2d.draw(((BasicHexagon) h).getCurrentTransform()); // this is a transformed Shape
} else {
    g2d.drawPolygon(h.getBase()); // this is a Polygon
}
```

Any better ways I'm missing out on, or any way that this isn't being called correctly?

Comment: Thats easy to debug, if you're working methodically: verify your gradient paints what you *think* it paints by filling the whole screen. That should provide a very obvious hint.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise the point offset was relative to the whole panel, instead of the `Shape` being painted!